# How to pass data between components in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have made 2 components :
1) content (which displays data using fetch() )
2) pagination (total 5 pages 16 objects per page )

I have made 2 state variables called `start:0` and `end:16`. Now whenever user clicks on page numbers I want to inject start and end state variables from pagination component to content component.

Logic for passing start and end variables to content is as follows:
initially end=16*1 (1 is multiplied because page 1) and start= end-16 i.e start=0

end = 16*2 (2 is multiplied because page 2) and start=end-16 i.e start=16

These start and end variables are passed in `.slice()` of content component so that onClick:
 page 1 it should display article 0 to 16 
page 2 it should display article 16 to 32 and so on till page 5

Below is code of pagination and content component:

content.js :

```
class Content extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[],
            loading:true,
            callmatchinfo: false,
            matchid:''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches:res.slice(this.props.start,this.props.end),  <---add new start and end everytime we click on new page number
        loading:false
      });
    })
    }

  viewstats(matchid){
    this.setState({
        callmatchinfo: true,
        matchid: matchid
    });
  }

  rendermatchinfo(){
    return <Matchinfo matchid={this.state.matchid} />
  }

    renderMatches() {
        return this.state.matches.map(match => {
            return (
                <div className="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p className="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                        <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                        <div className="winner">
                            <h3>WINNER</h3>
                            <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="stats">
                            <button type="button" onClick= {()=>{this.viewstats(match.id)}} className="btn btn-success">View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
        }
        else if(this.state.callmatchinfo){
        return <Matchinfo match_id={this.state.matchid} />
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.renderMatches()}
              </div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.callmatchinfo ? this.rendermatchinfo() : ''}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

pagination.js:

```
class Pagination extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            start:0,
            end:16
        };
    }

    handleClick(){
        this.setState{
            end:getpagenumber()*16,
            start:end-16
        }
    }

    getpagenumber(val){
        return val;
    }


  render() {
    let{start,end} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Content/>
          <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
               <li {this.getpagenumber(1)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li {this.getpagenumber(2)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li {this.getpagenumber(3)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li{this.getpagenumber(4)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li{this.getpagenumber(5)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Screenshot which displays match articles till 16 which is end=16 :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a parent component to communicate the two components, for example:

```jsx
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        start: 0,
        end: 16,
    };

    onChangePagination = (start, end) => {
        this.setState({
            start,
            end,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { start, end } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Content start={start} end={end} />
                <Pagination
                    onChange={this.onChangePagination} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

There's another change you need to do in he pagination component, and that is to call the `onChange` callback when values change.

```jsx
handleClick() {
    const end = (getpagenumber() * 16);
    const start = (end - 16);
    this.setState({
        end: end,
        start: start,
    });
    this.props.onChange(start, end);
}


renderMatches() {
    // Slide matches before looping, props will have the
    // values from the pagination component.
    return this.state.matches.slice(this.props.start, this.props.end)
        .map(match => (
            <div className="col-lg-3">
                <div id="content">
                    <p className="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                    <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                    <p>VS</p>
                    <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                    <div className="winner">
                        <h3>WINNER</h3>
                        <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="stats">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={ () => this.viewstats(match.id) }
                            className="btn btn-success">
                            View Stats</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    );
}
```

You probably might want to remove the local state from Pagination component, a you don't really need it.

Comment: So you are saying I should wrap up content and pagination component inside another component am I right ? I have updated the question with screenshot it displays 16 match articles on page 1 now onClick page 2 it should render match articles from 17 to 33 and similarly for remaining pages.

Comment: Yeap, if you are not using redux, mobox or any other library like that, you will have to use a parent component to communicate the children.

Comment: He'll also need to add a `componentWillReceiveProps` to `Content` to slice state when the new start and end values are passed in. With this approach, it's best to make the initial api call once, save all records in state of `Content` and then on render you can just slice your display data by `this.props.start` and `this.props.end`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I am new to ReactJS so could not understand your approach completely but you can see that I am using `fetch()` which returns 577 JSON objects out of which I only require 16 per page that's why I am using `.slice()` on `res` if possible can you post your answer. I understood that instead of making fresh API calls again and again we can store it.

Comment: @Crysfel Do I need to add `componentWillReceiveProps` as said by @ChaseDeAnda as I am new to Reactjs I am not familiar with `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I agree with @ChaseDeAnda, you should fetch your data in `componentDidMount` then add it to state, then you can do the slice in render. i don't see the need to use `componentWillReceiveProps`, let me update my answer

Comment: @stonerock I updated my answer,, when rendering the matches you need to slice the array before looping ;)

Answer (score 2):

Crysfel has the simplest correct solution in that you need a parent component to manage the data, and pass it down to its children as props, but there is another way which lends itself better to larger projects.

If you're just learning, or you're doing something small, definitely don't use it, but [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) is another way.

Simply put, it's a highly sophisticated bucket in which to put your state.  Now, instead of components caring about what their own state is, you put non-presentational state in the redux store, and the components read from the store with selectors.

In your case, you'd fire an action when `Pagination` is clicked to mutate the store, which would cause components listening for whatever data is changed to update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass `start` and `end` props , simply do this:

```
....
render() {
    let{start,end} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Content start={start} end={end} />

.....
```

This should answer your specific question how to pass props to `Content` component.

This may help you, but i think you should consider some code refactor anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function that updates state from `Content` to `Pagination`:

Move this code to a separate function in `Content`:

```jsx
updatePage(start, end) {
    fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.setState({
                // Add new start and end everytime we click on new page number.
                matches: res.slice(start, end),
                loading: false,
            });
        });
}
```

Then pass this down as a prop to `Pagination`:

```jsx
<Pagination updatePage={this.updatePage} />
```

Then, each time you update a page in `Pagination`, call `this.props.updatePage`:

```jsx
handleClick() {
    const end = this.getpagenumber() * 16;
    const start = end - 16;
    this.setState({
        end,
        start,
    });
    this.props.updatePage(start, end);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Simple update to `Content` to only fetch all data one time and then use props to slice the matches on each render:

```jsx
class Content extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches: [],
            loading: true,
            callmatchinfo: false,
            matchid: '',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('api/matches')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                // On mount, load all data and save it in state.
                this.setState({
                    allData: res,
                    loading: false,
                });
            });
    }

    renderMatches() {
        // Here we use slice on all the data and only return
        // 15 matches at a time for rendering.
        return this.state.allData.slice(this.props.start, this.props.end)
            .map(match => (
                <div className="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p className="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                        <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                        <div className="winner">
                            <h3>WINNER</h3>
                            <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="stats">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                onClick={
                                    () => { this.viewstats(match.id) }
                                }
                                className="btn btn-success">
                                View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {...}
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: So in your code Pagination is child component of content am I right ?

Comment: @stonerock Yes, Pagination is a child of Content. I couldn't see how you are nesting them right now, so I took a guess.

Comment: @stonerock Updated answer to include only pulling the data once.

Comment: Great it is very helpful.

Comment: no need of `componentWillReceiveProps` am I right ?

Comment: @stonerock right, you won't need it as long as you pass `start` and `end` as props to `Content`